# Show html as a new tab for print

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

In my app when the user clicks on a certain button, i will call an `API` and the `API` returns an `HTML` as a response, this `HTML` is a page (with and image and a few text) and i want to show this `HTML` in a new tab to my user and i also want to offer the user to print this page, how can i achieve this?
I tried `windows.open` but i'm not sure how i can use the response's `HTML` as the source for this page.
Is it even possible to do something like this in `ReactJS` ?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I can think about is creating an hidden container under your `body` element and placing your HTML into it. Then use the `@media print` magic to hide the page's content and display the printing element only.

For example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>This is my amazing title</title>
        <style>
            #print-section {
                display: none;
            }

            @media print {
                body > * {
                    display: none;
                }

                #print-section {
                    display: block;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>A lot of content</h1>
        <p>A lot of text will be displayed here</p>

        <div id="print-section">
            <!-- HTML code will be rendered into this section -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a `ReactJS` way to do this ?, i really want to avoid manually changing the `dom`, but i will consider your solution if there really is no other way, thx

Comment: I am not sure if there is any solution offered using ReactJS (I am not familiar with this framework). Although, you are trying to append new HTML content to an existing page using API call, so I assume you'll have to manually change the DOM this way or another..